# replace multiple spaces with new line php

Tags: php, html, regex, mailer

I got a variable that loos like this:

```
<b>Hight: </b></span><span>1.78 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><b>Bust: </b></span><span>86 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><b>waist: </b></span><span>64 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><b>Hips: </b></span><span>93 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><b>Pants: </b></span><span>26 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><b>Shoes: </b></span><span>40 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><b>Hair: </b></span><span>brown &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><b>Eyes: </b></span><span>blue</span>
```

that output this:

**Hight:** 1.78     **Bust:** 86     **waist:** 64     **Hips:** 93     **Pants:** 26     **Shoes:** 40     **Hair:** brown     **Eyes:** blue

My question is, how do I make this 5 -> `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`
turn into a `<br>` tag.

I was thinking about something like this, but of course its not working:
`$customField = str_replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","<br>",$customField);`

Keep in mind that this code part of a mailer.

Thank you.

Comment: you have 5 in the replace but only 4 in the code?

Comment: `$var = str_replace(str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5), '<br/>', $data);` with $data containing your variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have 1 space and 4 `&nbsp;`, use:

```
$customField = str_replace(" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", "<br />", $customField);
```